# How to remember username for next time on iPhone app?

Tags: ios

I am working on an iPhone/iOS app. It has a login page with two text fields "email" & "Password".Now i want to save email.
i.e When I logged out it should remember the email address so it doesn't have to be input again.
Please tell me how can I save email.

Comment: Do you know what is the [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) please do some google

Comment: if it is sensitive try storing data in keychain for better security.

Answer (score 2):

If you **don't consider email sensitive.** Use `NSUserDefaults`...

**Saving**

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:@"example@email.com" forKey:@"email"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
```

**Retrieving**

```
// getting an NSString
NSString *emailString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"email"];\
```

**IMPROVE ANSWER**

If you **consider email sensitive.** Use `keychain` instead.

**To store**

```
KeychainItemWrapper *keychain = 
 [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"MyAppLoginData" accessGroup:nil];
[keychain setObject:loginStr forKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount];
[keychain setObject:pwdStr forKey:(id)kSecValueData];
```

**To query**

```
NSString *login = [keychain objectForKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount];
NSString *pwd = [keychain objectForKey:(id)kSecValueData];
```

**To Delete:**

```
[keychain resetKeychainItem];
```

To do this you will first need to add [KeychainItemWrapper](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GenericKeychain/Listings/Classes_KeychainItemWrapper_h.html) in you project.
Another important aspects of using keychain to store data is

The data is persistent even after app uninstall-install

Data can be shared across apps too. Read more [here](http://shaune.com.au/ios-keychain-sharing-data-between-apps/)

Comment: You need to add `[prefs synchronize];` too in saving `NSUserDefaults`

Comment: IT's a VERY bad idea to save sensitive information in NSUserDefaults. Have a look at the keychain.

Comment: @AhmedZ.You don't need synchronise unless you want it to save immediately. NSUserDefaults will save automatically at time intervals.

Comment: @Ty -  need to synchronize or saving the values otherwise the memory will be deallocated

Comment: @CW0007007 its not sensitive. its an email not a password

Comment: You don't consider your email sensitive ?

Comment: @CW0007007 read carefully. OP only wants email. Not password.

Comment: @CW0007007 updated answer. Now OP can choose for himself whether email is sensitive or not. Thanks

Comment: @Ty_  This iPhone/iOS app I have developed using phonegap. So can you please tell me where do I have to implement the above code?

Comment: @user2240189 Saving email code goes in the Login button click method. Retrieving email code goes in the ViewController.m where you want to retrieve the email.

Answer (score 0):

In this case `email` is a part of user credentials, needed to login. So i would say **it is sensitive information**. Please **do not ever use** `NSUserDefaults` for storing sensitive data, that belongs to user. These defaults are stored as plist in binary format, they are not encrypted. Use [Keychain Services API
provided by iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html) instead.